# Getting component tier details of azure database using API

Tags: database, azure

I need to get component tier details of a database in Azure.
I am using :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505708.aspx

I have tried both :

1.Used management certificate string of publish settings file to make a X509 certificate which I have added in the request.

2.Used the access token obtained from API management section from Azure for adding as the authorization header.

But the code throws an exception 401 : "Unauthorized"

[image]

Please help me with the same. Thank you.

[image: getting AD token]
[image: updated header]

Comment: Thank you for sharing the screenshot. I believe there's an issue with your `Authorization` header. It should be something like `Bearer: some really long random string`. Can you update your question and include how are you getting the access token from Azure AD?

Comment: Please add a space after `Bearer:` in line 196 of your code. It should be `Bearer: `. See if that solves the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot :)
just one doubt more (as everything is new to me)
My API call access a database. How is the client Id, token Id and secret name of the cloud service of AD related to that database ?
(cz it shows invalid token)

Comment: For connecting to a database, you would use good old connection string :). This whole thing is for accessing Azure Resource Manager API. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making a request using `Azure Resource Manager (API) API`, you would need to pass `Authorization` header which should contain a `Bearer` token. You acquire that token by authenticating against an Azure Active Directory.

To learn more about authenticating an ARM API request, please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx.

Comment: I used publish file settings file to authenticate my call
won't it work?

Comment: In that case, you would need to include management certificate in the request: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx#bk_cert.

Comment: yes, I created a X509 certificate from the management certificate string and added it in the call but still unauthorized.

Comment: Please go back and update your question with all the steps you have taken. Please provide as much details as possible including screenshots. Things tend to lose perspective in the comments :). Thanks.